# WooCommerce - How to limit the short product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

in WooCommerce, How can I limit the short product description in the shop page? i added this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5);
```

but can't limit it to 40 charachters.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of editing files directly within the plugin (which is a very bad idea because once update the plugin and all of your changes will be lost!)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'limit_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1);
function limit_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
    if (!is_product()) {
        $post_excerpt = substr($post_excerpt, 0, 20);
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Then paste this in your **functions.php** file of your theme.

and use this line where you want to display product description -

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ); ?>
```

use this code to **change Limit on the Shop Page not Product-detailed Page**.

Comment: Thanks!!! is there any solution to limit No. of words? not charachters.

Comment: please check my next post . use -- $pieces = explode(" ", $post_excerpt);
        $post_excerpt = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 10));

Comment: In future, please do not copy content from elsewhere without clear attribution. It is seen as plagiarism. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
function et_excerpt_length($length) {
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type=="product") return 40;
        return 20; /*Your default excerpt length*/
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'et_excerpt_length');
```

adding it in function.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for limit no of words -

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'limit_woocommerce_short_description', 10, 1);
function limit_woocommerce_short_description($post_excerpt){
    if (!is_product()) {
        $pieces = explode(" ", $post_excerpt);
        $post_excerpt = implode(" ", array_splice($pieces, 0, 20));

    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

**explode** breaks the original string into an array of words, array_splice lets you get certain ranges of those words, and then **implode** combines the ranges back together into single strings.

use this code to change Limit on the Shop Page not Product-detailed Page.