# Why this function is shortening also my Archive Description?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I don't understand why function below influence `woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description()`
Where is connection between those two? Shouldn't this work only for `woocommerce_short_description`?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'limit_woocommerce_short_description' );

function limit_woocommerce_short_description( $post_post_excerpt ) { 

    if(!is_product()) { // add in conditionals
        $text = $post_post_excerpt; 
        $words = 24; // change word length
        $more = ' […]'; // add a more cta
        
        $post_post_excerpt = wp_trim_words( $text, $words, $more );
    }
    return $post_post_excerpt; 
}
```

Comment: This is what the function do:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/

Comment: This post can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362985/woocommerce-how-to-limit-the-short-product-description

Comment: @MarioAbbruscato i understand what the function do. I don't get why this is automatically applied to my archive description. I'm using ```echo apply_filters('woocommerce_short_description', get_the_excerpt() )``` to get shorter description of the product in a loop, but it also works where i'm not applying this.

Comment: Are you able to find the string "apply_filters" in all your php files ?   So you know when the function is called and where.  Just to have an idea.   Another thing you can do is to change temporarily the function to see if  changes are applyed  to  archive description also.   

So you need to know :  which files calls the function  ,  which archives are effected by changes. In conlcusion  you can create onother filter  and use it  where you need  and check if  other archives are effected.

Comment: Here is your answer -  woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description is using wc_format_content to return the description which is calling the filter woocommerce_short_description :)

Comment: @MarioAbbruscato easiest way probably ```echo wp_trim_words( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', get_the_excerpt() ), 24, ' [...]' );``` Thanks for your input.